# Is there a bug in the minimum function?

Tags: haskell

I have a list `mins` of 415920 numbers, all supposed to be closed to `0.1`:

```
Prelude Lib> take 5 mins
[9.83610706554002e-2,9.847021825032128e-2,9.847021825032128e-2,9.898395035483082e-2,9.898395035483082e-2]
```

However:

```
Prelude Lib> minimum mins
0.10087849151477328
```

The `minimum` function is not supposed to return the minimum ?

This result sounds plausible:

```
Prelude Lib> foldr min 100000 mins
1.1763616593045858e-4
```

Is it a bug, or I misunderstand `minimum` ?

Similar issue with `maximum`:

```
Prelude Lib> maximum mins
3261145.0627630088
Prelude Lib> foldr max 0 mins
0.1207868227600914
```

Sorting the list yields a third result for the maximum:

```
Prelude Lib> import Data.List as L
Prelude Lib L> mins' = sort mins
Prelude Lib L> head mins'
1.1763616593045858e-4
Prelude Lib L> last mins'
0.10295664278431726
```

And applying `minimum` and `maximum` on the sorted list yields a third result for the minimum:

```
Prelude Lib L> minimum mins'
0.10045801977483232
Prelude Lib L> maximum mins'
3261145.0627630088
```

## Edit

After @max630's comment, I've searched in the list with a text editor. The `3261145.0627630088` is indeed here, and there are some `NaN`:

```
NaN,NaN,3261145.0627630088
```

*Conclusion:* it looks like `minimum` gives a wrong result, and `maximum` gives the correct result.

`foldr max` gives a wrong result, `foldl max` gives the good one:

```
> foldl max 0 mins
3261145.0627630088
```

Comment: Does your list contain NaNs or other special values?

Comment: Can you share your list of numbers?

Comment: @max630 Yes !!!: `> any isNaN mins` 
`True`

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov It takes 8 MB in a `txt` file. I could share it with a gist. But it seems that max630 has found the reason.

Comment: @max630 If I do `filter (not . isNaN) mins'` then `minimum` gives the good result (the same as `foldr min`), but not `maximum`.

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov the list is in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/stla/ae8289f453f1433ba4b97a67f83a4626)

Comment: I'd expect `maximum` to return 3261145.0627630088 - it seems to be the correct value. Doesn't it do it?

Comment: @max630 Yes I've just written that in my edit.

Comment: Also, can you tell the version of GHC?

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov ghc 8-2.2

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The reason to all issues is that the list contains `NaN`. Apparently it violated the `Ord`'s  total ordering requirement[*], so you cannot expect algorithms which use the ordering - either picking minimum or sorting - to produce correct result when it is in the input. Instead they will produce something which depends on their internal implementation, and may be different depending on seemingly unimportant reasons, for example input order. You should filter it out before doing anything else.

[*] `Ord` does not have it laws written out explicitely (neither does `Eq` which NaN also breaks), but here example of breaking totality rule, as it is [described in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order) (thanks @sjakobi for correcting):

```
Prelude> let nan = 0 / 0
Prelude> nan
NaN
Prelude> nan <= 1
False
Prelude> 1 <= nan
False
Prelude>
```

Comment: Yes ok, thanks. I think a sensible `minimum/maximum` function should return `NaN` in such a case (like R does for example).

Comment: The problem that they do not know about NaN, they just use methods provided by Ord. And Ord does not have a way to say "hey this value is special, abort everything and return this as a sign that it is special".

Comment: Yes I understand what happens. I've found this interesting discussion about `NaN` in Julia: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/7866

Comment: Something "funny": define `infty = 1/0` and try `max nan infty` and `max infty nan`. This is respectively `NaN` and `Infinity`.

Comment: Something good to know : [NaN-aware min and max in Haskell](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ieee754-0.8.0/docs/Numeric-IEEE.html#g:2).

Comment: It would be great to have these issues documented on `Float`'s `Eq` and `Ord` instances. They are defined in `GHC.Classes` in `ghc-prim`.

Comment: @max630: You describe violated __totality__, not antisymmetry. (And totality is defined with `<=` and `>=`.)

Comment: @sjakobi thanks. I had in mind `a > b` = `not (a <= b)`, then it would become antisymmetry.  But such replacement is not valid if there is no totality